# loading data from Elasticsearch into python using Pycharm

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dataframe, pycharm

3.3. I have a very basic problem
I want to get the dataset I have in an Elasticsearch index into Python for processing.(like getting the data into a python dataframe)
Can someone please help. If someone can share a sample code etc. would be highly vauable

Answer (score 0):

You may use [elasticsearch-dsl-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py) third-party library for this purpose. It gives you high-level API to interact with elasticsearch. For more information read the documentation.